# Heroku Pymongo fails deployment at "Preparing static assets"

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pymongo, flask-restful

I am trying to deploy a Flask-Restful app which has the following dependencies:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-RESTful==0.2.12
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
aniso8601==0.85
argparse==1.2.1
gunicorn==19.1.1
itsdangerous==0.24
pymongo==2.7.2
pytz==2014.9
six==1.8.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

When I remove the pymongo package from the file and `git push heroku master` everything is ok and working.
When I add it again and try to deploy the process stuck at:

```
       Successfully installed pymongo
       Cleaning up...
-----> Preparing static assets
```

And then it hits timeout after 15 minutes. Any ideas why it stucks there and how can I escape it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
heroku config: set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 1
```

This for the moment fixed the problem so the upload is successful. I am still waiting for the Heroku's team support, they said they are working on the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem - the syntax I needed to use was slightly different: `heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1`